# "Input string was not in a correct format" when setting a NumericUpDown value

Tags: c#

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

I am using a file to set bunch of in my program. I am reading the content of a file by using separators. My text file looks like this: `The Message$1$5001&5002&5003`

When I am trying to read a value of a numeric values in my file I am getting error: `Input string was not in a correct format.` on line: `nudInterval.Value = decimal.Parse(setting);`

This is how I do it:

```
if (!lastUsed.EmptyFile())
{
    string[] allSettings = lastUsed.Text.Split('$');
    int settingCount = 0;

    foreach (string setting in allSettings)
    {
        settingCount++;

        if (settingCount == 1)
        {
            txtText.Text = setting;
        }
        else if (settingCount == 2)
        {
            if (setting == "0") tbType.SelectedTab = tbInterval;
            else tbType.SelectedTab = tbRange;
        }
        else if (settingCount == 3)
        {
            nudInterval.Value = decimal.Parse(setting);
        }
        else if (settingCount == 4)
        {
            nudMin.Value = decimal.Parse(setting);
        }
        else if (settingCount == 5)
        {
            nudMax.Value = decimal.Parse(setting);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the numeric up/down control, it's the `int.Parse()` method. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) says that you get the exception when the input string is not in the correct format. And if your input contains a decimal, it's probably not in the correct format. `5001&5002&5003` would not be a valid integer either.

Comment: Do NumericUpDowns support decimals?

Comment: Have you debugged the error? What is there in _setting_ when error came. Also do _.Trim()_ inside .Parse(), you might get some space. Secondly try using _switch_ statement instead of if-else.

Comment: And why in the world would a `switch` statement instead of an if-else statement fix *anything*?

Comment: @agent-j, yes it support decimals. This is why I have parsed to decimal.

Comment: @Cody Gray, I might use switch, but as of right now I'm kind of sketching.

Comment: Please notice that I have had mistake in my file. I haven't use $ all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because half of your separators are &, not $.

This means you are trying to execute

```
nudInterval.Value = decimal.Parse("5001&5002&5003");
```

which will fail.

If those are valid values, you could change your split statement:

```
string[] allSettings = lastUsed.Text.Split(new char[] {'$', '&'});
```

or replace & with $ before splitting:

```
string[] allSettings = lastUsed.Text.Replace('&', '$').Split('$');
```

Comment: O Duh! Wow I have looked at it at least 4 times and didn't spot my mistake. LOL. Human (mine) stupidity is infinite I must say.

Comment: You already earned answer point :) But... Let's say I don't want single character as separator (possible problem if user types a message) would `string[] allSettings = lastUsed.Text.Split(new string[] {'$&$'});` make separator by looking at 3 characters?

Comment: Take a look at the first option for changing the split statement in the answer (may have updated after you asked). Answer is yes: you can use a char array to split on mult values.

Comment: I'm not sure how to split the string using multiple characters. Trying your first example doesn't seem to work. Perhaps I got the overloads confused.

Comment: Oh! Never mind, I thing I have found a good example similar to yours. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is the message of the `FormatException` that `int.Parse` is throwing. What is `setting`? You think it's a string that is a valid number, but it's not. It will probably have a `&` hanging off of it.

What happens if you add `Console.WriteLine(setting)`, `MessageBox.Show(setting)` or just set a break point and look at `setting` in the debugger?

Comment: Well, I'm sure that my checks are correct. The problem existed in formatting in my file.