# How to split using multiple characters?

Tags: c#, split

I am trying to make error free user input. When there is a one split symbol user might type it and create an error which I must fix before executing creating more lines of code. Is there a way of splitting a string using for example `$%$` instead of just `$` character?

This is how I do splitting using one character:

```
if (!lastUsed.EmptyFile())
{
    string[] allSettings = lastUsed.Text.Split('$');
    int settingCount = 0;

    foreach (string setting in allSettings)
    {
        settingCount++;

        if (settingCount == 1)
        {
            txtText.Text = setting;
        }
        else if (settingCount == 2)
        {
            if (setting == "0") tbType.SelectedTab = tbInterval;
            else tbType.SelectedTab = tbRange;
        }
        else if (settingCount == 3)
        {
            nudInterval.Value = decimal.Parse(setting);
        }
        else if (settingCount == 4)
        {
            nudMin.Value = decimal.Parse(setting);
        }
        else if (settingCount == 5)
        {
            nudMax.Value = decimal.Parse(setting);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)? It accepts an array of characters. Sounds like that's what you want: just specify multiple characters to split on.

Comment: This was already part of your last http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798603/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-when-setting-a-numericupdown-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a string as the delimiter.

```
string[] delim = new string[] {"$%$"};

string[] allSettings = lastUsed.Text.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.None);
```